# what does this code snippet mean

Tags: java, android

code snippet:

```
  for( String token : tokens ) 
        {
            try
            {
                Url url = as("mycompany", "someapikey").call(shorten(token));
             }
         }
```

what do the 'as' and the 'call' mean. Are they keywords in java?

i was browsing and i found this code and i would like to understand what it means.

thank you in advance.

Comment: They are not Keywords. Likely there is a static import at the top... something like "import static some.package.Class.as;"

Comment: where did you find this?  The as() and call() functions aren't any well-known functions I'm aware of, they could be user-defined.  Especially the as().

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's using the `bit.ly` library to shorten URLs.  the `for` loop is iterating through strings in a collection, `tokens`.  it then creates a shortened URL via the bit.ly library. These aren't keywords in Java, they are just method names.

android bit.ly library: http://code.google.com/p/bitlyj/

Answer (score 0):

No, they are regular methods. The `as()` method should be in the class this is from (or a superclass), while the `call()` method is defined for the type returned by `as()`.

It would be helpful to have a link back to the original source where you found this, as more context is often useful.

Answer (score 0):

`as` and `call` are not keywords in Java.

It seems that `as(String s1, String s2)` is a method that returns an object that has a method `call(..)`.

That method `call(..)` is invoked on the return value of `as(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a static import?

For example, if class Foo has a static method `as()`, you can use

```
import static Foo.as;

{
  //now can do this:
  as();  //equal to Foo.as();
}
```